# Use video_player to play the video, it made a mistake

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I used the video_player plugin, according to the example, I couldn't play the video and got the error.(in iOS simulator)

I add the following entry to your Info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist:

```
>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>

VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
            // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
            print('initialize${_controller.value.toString()}');
            setState(() {});
        });
  }

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
        child: _controller.value.initialized
            ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        )
            : Container(),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
                _controller.value.isPlaying
                    ? _controller.pause()
                    : _controller.play();
            });
        },
        child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
    ),
);
```

}

I wish I could play the video, but I got the error.

```
[C2.1 FBF3D053-02DA-4FC7-A153-96BA9F8DAF09 192.168.0.96:56397<->45.249.110.23:443]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 1.601s, DNS @0.000s took 0.002s, TCP @0.005s took 0.249s, TLS took 0.546s
    bytes in/out: 27647/1397, packets in/out: 22/4, rtt: 0.256s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 8
    "LocalDataTask <698CEEC9-45A4-41BC-9449-C8E33C4EB550>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <698CEEC9-45A4-41BC-9449-C8E33C4EB550>.<2>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
    [C1.1 441C4C64-313B-4F7D-9B25-8454C615F6BC 192.168.0.96:56396<->45.249.110.23:80]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 2.161s, DNS @0.003s took 0.006s, TCP @0.012s took 0.001s
    bytes in/out: 579/346, packets in/out: 1/1, rtt: 0.256s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
```

And i have print the '_controller.value':

```
VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:01:57.312000, size: Size(1280.0, 720.0), position: 0:00:00.000000, buffered: [DurationRange(start: 0:00:00.000000, end: 0:00:00.021000)], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: truevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null)
```

Comment: You can't play video on iOS simulator. Can you run on physical device or android emulator?

Comment: thank you,when i run on the phone,it works.

Comment: glad to hear that, good luck!